# Conditional onComplete action

Tags: xpages, el

In the onComplete event I have this code:

```
<xp:this.onComplete>
    <![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:dynamicContent1}");]]>
</xp:this.onComplete>
```

This works fine because I essential want two partialRefreshes in the same event handler. However, this partial refresh however, fires some times when I don't want it to so I need to make it conditional something like

if (sessionScope.get("ssVariable") == true) {
   do the partialRefreshGet
}

but this is expression language and not sure how to make it a conditional statement, and not sure how to get the sessionscope variable passed to it.

Is there a place that one can get some documentation and examples of EL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate the CSJS code as a string in SSJS code:

```
<xp:this.onComplete>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:
            if (sessionScope.get("ssVariable") == true) {
                "XSP.partialRefreshGet('" +
                    getComponent("dynamicContent1").getClientId(facesContext) + 
                "')"
            }
        }]]>
</xp:this.onComplete>
```

If the condition is true then the result of this SSJS code is a string like this:

```
XSP.partialRefreshGet('view:_id1:dynamicContent1')
```

This code is then used on client side for onComplete event.

If the condition is false then the onComplete event code is empty.